# Error connecting IMAP server with python imaplib and mailcow

Tags: python, imaplib, dovecot, mailcow

I just install a mailcow mail server on a ubuntu 22.04(fresh install) vps, i can connect well with my mail client (Evolution), but have issue when trying to connect from a python script using imaplib:

my client side is Ubuntu 22.10 Mate with Python 3.10

```
import imaplib 
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("mail.mysite.com", 143) 
imap.login('me@mysite.com','a_strong_password')
```

getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/home/cc1/python/mail/imap_test.py", line 12, in <module>
     imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("mail.mysite.com", 143)   
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/imaplib.py", line 1323, in __init__
     IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port, timeout)   
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/imaplib.py", line 202, in __init__
     self.open(host, port, timeout)   
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/imaplib.py", line 1336, in open
     IMAP4.open(self, host, port, timeout)   
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/imaplib.py", line 312, in open
     self.sock = self._create_socket(timeout)   
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/imaplib.py", line 1327, in _create_socket
     return self.ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock,   
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 513, in wrap_socket
     return self.sslsocket_class._create(   
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1071, in _create
     self.do_handshake()   
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1342, in do_handshake
     self._sslobj.do_handshake()
 ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)
```

I already try using ssl context with both options:

```
# PROTOCOL_SSLv23
# PROTOCOL_TLS
# PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT
# PROTOCOL_TLSv1
# PROTOCOL_TLSv1_1
# PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
```

here the config of my mail client working well:
[mail client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9teS.png)

i guess its about some server side config, but i'm new to mailcow and dovecot

Answer (score 1):

Just find out my problem:

replacing
`imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("mail.mysite.com", 143)`
by
`imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("mail.mysite.com")`

and then it works well

Comment: Yes, 143 is for plain text or StartTLS connections. 993 is for SSL/TLS connections.